# Relative performance of writing locators in PageObjects or Properties files

Tags: java, performance, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I was going through an Automation Framework that follows Page Object Model but is a bit unstructured. It grew over the period of time and now has around hundred of tests running. While running through the framework, I noticed that some QA had followed writing the webpage locators in the properties file and other in the pageobjects itself. So I was wondering,

***How the performance of the tests will vary in bigger test suites(say 1000s of test) if webpage locators follow the different declaration in Java*** as below:

**1. In Properties file(s)**

Storing the locator using the properties file and then referencing them.

`loginBtn=login`

`driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("loginBtn"))).click();`

**2. In seperate Locator class(es)**

Storing the locator using a dedicated locator class and referencing them.

`By loginBtn = By.id("login");`

`driver.findElement(locators.loginBtn).click();`

**3. In PageObject class**

Storing the locator using pageobjects classes itself and create a By object for every element.

`driver.findElement(loginBtn).click();`

**4. In Page Factory**

Storing the locator using page factory and initializing it.

`@FindBy(id="login")
 WebElement loginBtn;`

I would appreciate if someone can provide a detailed performance analysis of these strategies and in what situation can we prefer the either of the above strategy.